# Rich text in Flash TLF

Tags: actionscript-3, text, flash-cs5, richtext

How does one apply rich text to Flash at runtime?  Specifically, I need to dynamically create bullet-points and paragraphs with line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `TextField` and set it's `htmlText` property to the text with markup.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the Text Layout Framework, you can convert your textFlow to import the TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT constant to achieve HTML text.

```
var textFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(myText, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT, myConfiguration);
```